# Psychopy can import matplotlib but can't import pyplot though it's on my Mac

Tags: matplotlib, importerror, psychopy

I'm having problems importing pyplot into psychopy on my MacBook running OS X Yosemite. I have psychopy v1.82.01 installed.

My program contains: `import matplotlib` (which works) and `from matplotlib import pyplot` (which gives the following error):

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Applications/PsychoPy2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/matplotlib/ft2font.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Applications/PsychoPy2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/matplotlib/ft2font.so
>   Reason: image not found

But I DO have pyplot.py on the Mac here:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.py

How do I get psychopy to import it from this other folder?

Thanks,
Philip

Comment: Well the error says that it cant load libfreetype. So installing this library might solve the issue....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlotlib (at least some parts of it I guess) depend on this font library which is distributed as part of X11 (now known as XQuartz) so try installing XQuartz from here and see if that fixes it:
xquartz.macosforge.org

Comment: Thanks Jon. I already had Quartz 2.7.6 but 2.7.7 seems to have done the trick. Brilliant.